# Pygame "catcher" (Sprite) does not move. Python Crash Course 13-5

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a catcher move in order to catch some falling balls.
The balls and the catcher are Sprites ( in order to use pygame.sprite.groupcollide).
However, the catcher stands still and does not obey any orders.
I don't get any order.
I am a noob.

I have checked every function, but I can't find any reason.

MAIN CODE:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.sprite import Group
import game_functions as gf
from settings import Settings
from guy import Guy


def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((settings.screen_width, settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Catcher game')
    balls = Group()
    guys = Group()
    guy = Guy(screen, settings)
    guys.add(guy)
    while True:
        for guy in guys:
            gf.check_events(guy)
        guy.update()
        gf.update_ball (settings, screen, guys, balls)
        gf.check_ball_bottom (settings, balls)
        gf.update_screen (screen, guys, balls, settings)

run_game()
```

FUNCTIONS:

```
import pygame
import sys
from ball import Ball
from settings import Settings
from guy import Guy

def check_events(guy):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.display.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events (event, guy )
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            check_keyup_events (event, guy)

def check_keydown_events (event, guy):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        guy.moving_right == True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        guy.moving_left == True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
        pygame.display.quit()
        sys.exit()

def check_keyup_events (event, guy):
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        guy.moving_right == False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        guy.moving_left == False

def create_new_ball (screen, settings, balls):
    new_ball = Ball (screen, settings)
    balls.add(new_ball)

def update_ball (settings, screen, guys, balls):
    #we have to check if there is any ball left
    if len(balls) == 0:
        create_new_ball (screen, settings, balls)

    collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide (balls, guys, True, False)

def check_ball_bottom (settings, balls):
    for ball in balls.copy():
        if ball.rect.y > settings.screen_height:
            balls.remove(ball)

def update_screen (screen, guys, balls, settings):
    screen.fill(settings.bg_color)

    for ball in balls:
        ball.update()
    balls.draw(screen)
    for guy in guys:
        guy.blitme()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

THE CATCHER CLASS:

```
import pygame

from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Guy(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, settings):
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/guy.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = settings

        #set character position
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom

        #set flags
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_left = False

        self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)

    def update (self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.setting.width:
            self.center += self.settings.guy_speed
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0 :
            self.center -= self.settings.guy_speed

        self.rect.centerx = self.center


    def blitme(self):
        self.screen.blit (self.image, self.rect)
        #IS this method necessaire if I use guys.draw()?
```

I don't get any error message.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect at least part of your problem is that you are using `==` instead of `=` for assigning values to variables. For example,

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    guy.moving_right == True
```

should be

```
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    guy.moving_right = True
```

The reason this didn't show any errors is because it's still valid python to do an equality comparison on its own like that.